# Sites with Google Maps slowing to a crawl

Tags: google-chrome, performance, graphics, google-maps

In Chrome (and, strangely, also in FireFox to a lesser extent) I'm having a problem with sites that use Google Maps: GMaps itself, Bikely, Strava etc. After a while, rendering of the map gets incredibly slow, panning is painful etc. During this time, the mouse is slow to respond. I get the feeling that it's JavaScript execution that is locking up somehow - but don't know how to verify. On some Strava pages, it can get so bad that simply moving the mouse over the map will take a second or more per redraw of the mouse cursor.

I've tried disabling some extensions (the ones left are things like Adblock, Collusion, LastPass, Chrome2Phone). Beyond that, I can't really think what to look for. I don't think it's just Google Maps either - perhaps it's the fact of panning around big images.

Any suggestions for ways to diagnose the problem, or possible fixes gratefully appreciated.

EDIT Further info: exactly the same symptoms in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. Using normal Google Maps is sort of ok, but apps built on it (especially Google Map Maker) are terrible. Usable for a little while, then everything in the app window gets slower and slower, including typing and moving the mouse. I'm mystified.

Comment: Have you recently updated your graphics drivers?

Comment: Could be a problem with your machine being slow... not sure how to specifically diagnose however :/

Comment: Tog: not that I know of. It's a pretty old box (~2006ish), XP Pro. Haven't touched the video card in a long time. But I've only been noticing this extreme slowness in the last month or two.

Comment: @SteveBennett - Load up a virtual machine and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Very interesting idea - will give that a go.